# Django aggregate, use of AND/OR operators in when condition

Tags: python, django, aggregate, django-queryset

With the following queryset I would like to add and / or condition in the when clause, but I get syntax error.
Is it possible to do it in a single queryset or should I split?

```
Game.objects.prefetch_related('schedule').filter(Q(team_home_id=625) | Q(team_away_id=625), schedule__date_time_start__lte=timezone.now())
  .aggregate(
    wins=Sum(Case(When(
      score_home__gt=F('score_away') & team_home_id=625 |
      score_away__gt=F('score_home') & team_away_id=625, then=1), 
      default=0, output_field=IntegerField()
    )),
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#when) you have to use `Q` objects when using complex conditions (just like you did in `filter`). An example:

```
When(Q(name__startswith="John") | Q(name__startswith="Paul"), then='name')
```